# Website isn't adapted for the mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

So, I'm developing the website and it works well on PC screen but doesn't work on mobile screen.

At first time website looked as ['before changes on mobile'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpCgU.jpg)

I thought the problem with size of main picture and changed the size from 700x700px to 500x500px. I changed the width of div with the description(below) from 1200px to 900px as well. And after that website looked as ['on mobile screen'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8qTA.jpg). As you can see,changes didn't help. The white line remained in the right side of mobile screen. I don't have any ideas how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried optimizing the view using the following code?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Perhaps you should also try repsonsive design frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: After the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> mobile screen loocked as [link](https://pp.userapi.com/c837331/v837331511/41efa/41ntzXKnJCw.jpg). Thank you for Bootstrap framework, I'll try it.

Comment: @ectuser Do you have an update on this? Did Bootstrap help? If so, I'd very happy about an accept (You can accept an anwer by clicking the tick below the downvote button).